# QGIS Expression Builder: returning pair of values (e.g.: coord)

Tags: qgis, coordinates, expression

Seems like this should be simple, meaning I'm probably "trying to do the wrong thing," but: I have a field (specifically, Label Placement's "*Offset X,Y*") that expects an input of type `double coord`. I want to do a data-defined override: pull the X and Y values from columns in the attribute table.

But, how do I return the two values as a single coord pair from the expression builder? Trying `[x,y]`, `(x,y)`, `{x,y}`, etc. all give a syntax error...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They must be converted to string in format `x,y`

You can use

```
"offset_x" || ',' || "offset_y"
```

or

```
format('%1,%2', "offset_x", "offset_y")
```

where `offset_x` and `offset_y` are your offset columns.